# "'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Why is npm not recognized?

I'm trying to learn react and get started using it. I have node installed, and the package create-react-app.

If I type in my command line, `npm -v` or `create-react-app -V`, it will return the current versions I have. Which is step one in my problem.

Step two would be checking the environment paths.

I have `C:\Users\hunte\AppData\Roaming\npm` in my paths and I even ran my bash command line as administrator with no such luck.

Step three I assume would be restarting my computer. (Obviously it didn't work)

How I installed and tried to step up react is like this...

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app my-app`

Then it returns `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

I'm lost, looking for some help to resolve this as I really eager to learn react.js.

Thank's to all who spend the time reading my question.

**Here's my cmd**

```
$ create-react-app test

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\hunte\desktop\test\test.

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test/ from C:\Users\hunte\desktop\test
Done.
```

Comment: so, `npm -v` works, but `npm install -g create-react-app` does not?

Comment: No, they both work. I did a npm install -g create-react-app and it installed react. and the npm -v just gives the version of npm.

Comment: so it's only `create-react-app test` that fails

Comment: @JaromandaX That is correct. I even just tried a `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and it worked and uninstalled it. Then I reinstalled it to only find the same problem I have at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

I've figured it out!

For everyone who runs into a similar problem all I did to get it to work was change CMDs.

I was using the Git Bash CMD as I like it better; however, I guess it doesn't work well with the system paths/environments.

All I did to fix this issue to run my ***default cmd*** as administrator and tried again. This time it worked and I was successful in creating the react package.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default Command Prompt worked for me. I was previously working on Hyper.